# Windows global hook for text box focus

Tags: c#, c++, windows, hook

I'm building a virtual keyboard for Windows (can't use the default keyboard, I need to block some keys and add custom ones) and I planned on using global hooks in order to display/hide the keyboard when needed.

I already have a simulated keyboard in WPF and I use the GotFocus/LostFocus methods for making it appear/disappear. But the problem is the keyboard should also work with third-party apps (i.e. Reader) so I need it to work without additional code. I looked at HCBT_SETFOCUS but it only gives me the window that has focus, not the UI element.

Is there a global event fired when a text box gains/loses focus?

Thanks!

Comment: [The only supported way to create a keyboard layout is through MKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)

Comment: @Mgetz MKLC would have been perfect but I need to remove the Windows key. The keyboard is part of an embedded WPF app and users shouldn't have access to the desktop.

Comment: My suggestion would be to either use embedded windows which may have different rules, or to physically modify the keyboard. An alternate suggestion would be to fudge it and make your own simulated keyboard, but that will be very painful.

Comment: I already have a simulated keyboard in WPF and I use the GotFocus/LostFocus methods for making it appear/disappear. But the problem is the keyboard should also work with third-party apps (i.e. Reader) so I need it to work without additional code.I looked at HCBT_SETFOCUS but it only gives the window that has focus, not the UI element.